# How to check if a number can be represented as the sum of two consecutive perfect cubes.

Tags: sequences-and-series, perfect-powers

How to check if a number can be represented as the sum of two consecutive perfect cubes.

for eg N = 35 can be represented as the sum of two consecutive perfect cubes 2<sup>3</sup> and
3<sup>3</sup>

Comment: You could solve the cubic $$2x^3+3x^2+3x+(1-k)=0$$ if $\ k\ $ is the given number.If there is a positive integer root then there is such a representation. Note that such a solution must be a divisor of $\ k-1\ $

Comment: This question has got nothing to do with *perfect numbers* $n$, which are those $n$ such that $\sigma(n)=2n$, where $\sigma(n)$ is the *sum of divisors* of $n$.  (So for example, $6$ is perfect since $\sigma(6)=1+2+3+6=2\cdot{6}$.)  I have therefore removed the **[perfect-numbers]** tag and replaced it with the **[perfect-powers]** tag, which I believe is more appropriate for this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $m^3$ be the largest perfect cube such that $m^3<\frac N 2$. If $N=m^3+(m+1)^3$ then you are done. If not then $N$ cannot be represented as the sum of two consecutive cubes.

Answer (score 0):

If you have factors of $N$ then you may use the fact that $m^3+(m+1)^3=(m^2+m+1)(2m+1)$.  Then the quadratic factor cannot have any $6k-1$ prime factors, so $2m+1$ must be a multiple of the product of all such factors appearing in $N$.  For instance, if $N=35$ then $2m+1$ must be a divisor of $35$ that's a multiple of $5$, and if this $N$ is to be a sum of two consecutive cubes at all then $m$ can only be $2$ or $17$.